# Running a program until networkx.check_planarity() returns True

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I have the following function that generates a graph.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import random
def random_graph(vertices, connectivity):
    #Creates random symmetric graph
    arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(vertices,vertices))
    sym = (arr+arr.T)
    
    #removing self loops with fixing diagonal
    np.fill_diagonal(sym,0)
    
    #connectivity of graph -> 0 for highest connections, 9 for least connections
    mat = (sym>connectivity).astype(int)
    
    #convert to dictionary
    G = {k:[i for i,j in enumerate(v) if j==1] for k,v in enumerate(mat)}
    return G
```

I use that function with a randomly generated connectivity, unfortunately the generated graph is not always planar, so I want to run the function until I get a planar graph. The planarity of the graph is checked with the function `check_planarity` from `networkx`. The function `check_planarity` returns a boolean, if it's true, the graph is planar, if false the graph is not planar and I need to generate a new graph until it's planar. This is what I have tried:

```
while True:
    random_connectivity = random.randint(4, 9)
    G = random_graph(5, random_connectivity)
    g = nx.Graph(G)
    planar = nx.check_planarity(g)
    if planar:
        break
    else: 
        pass
```

As you can see from the loop above, first I generate `random_connectivity`, them I create the graph with that connectivity and then with `networkx` I check the planarity. Then I try to check if it's planar or not and if not I run the program again. Unfortunately it doesn't work because it often returns a non planar graph. I also tried unpacking `planar` and checking the first element of the unpacked list but it doesn't work:

```
planar_check = [x[0] for x in planar]
```

When trying the line of code above I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\besan\OneDrive\Desktop\LAM da correggere\test.py", line 64, in <module>  
    planar_check = [x[0] for x in planar]
  File "c:\Users\besan\OneDrive\Desktop\LAM da correggere\test.py", line 64, in <listcomp>
    planar_check = [x[0] for x in planar]
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is there an error?  Does it hang?  Does it return a non-planar graph?

Comment: it returns a non planar graph. I added it to the question

Comment: `check_planarity()` returns a 2-element tuple - that's always truthy, you need to explicitly check the first element of the tuple for your result.

Comment: Could you please explain how I can check the first element in a tuple? I've updated the question explaining how I have just tried to do it but failed

Comment: Three possible ways to write it: `planar, _ = nx.check_planarity(g)`, `planar = nx.check_planarity(g)[0]`, or `if planar[0]:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by directly checking the first element of `planar` insead of unpacking it:

```
planar = nx.check_planarity(g)[0]
```